# Get word from string - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match

I am trying to extract a word that matches a specific pattern from various strings.

The strings vary in length and content.

For example:

I want to extract any word that begins with jac from the following strings and populate an array with the full words:

- I bought a jacket yesterday.
- Jack is going home.
- I want to go to Jacksonville.

The resulting array should be [jacket,Jack,Jacksonville]

I have been trying to use preg_match() but for some reason it won't work. Any suggestions???

```
$q = "jac";
$str = "jacket";
preg_match($q,$str,$matches);

print $matches[1];
```

This returns null :S. I dunno what the problem is.

Comment: Especially the regex you tried to use!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `preg_match` as:

```
preg_match("/\b(jac.+?)\b/i", $string, $matches);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/h38On)

Answer (score 1):

You've got to [read the manual](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) a few hundred times and it will eventually come to you.

Otherwise, what you're trying to capture can be expressed as "look for 'jac' followed by 0 or more letters* and make sure it's not preceded by a letter" which gives you: `/(?<!\\w)(jac\\w*)/i`

Here's an example with `preg_match_all()` so that you can capture *all* the occurences of the pattern, not just the first:

```
$q = "/(?<!\\w)(jac\\w*)/i";
$str = "I bought a jacket yesterday.
Jack is going home.
I want to go to Jacksonville.";

preg_match_all($q,$str,$matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

- Note: by "letter" I mean any "word character." Officially, it includes numbers and other "word characters." Depending on the exact circumstances, one may prefer \w (word character) or \b (word boundary.)

---

You can include extra characters by using a [character class](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php). For instance, in order to match any word character as well as single quotes, you can use `[\w']` and your regexp becomes:

```
$q = "/(?<!\\w)(jac[\\w']*)/i";
```

Alternatively, you can add an optional `'s` to your existing pattern, so that you capture "jac" followed by any number of word characters optionally followed by "'s"

```
$q = "/(?<!\\w)(jac\\w*(?:'s)?)/i";
```

Here, the `?:` inside the parentheses means that you don't actually need to capture their content (because they're already inside a pair of parentheses, it's unnecessary), and the `?` after the parentheses means that the match is optional.

Comment: Hey thanks for this! I really appreciate it. I was testing the code and realized that I would like to include quotes, such that, for example: "Jack's" would be matched from "Jack's brother is named Gary."

Comment: Would I use something like this: 
    /(?<!\\w)(jac\\w*'*\w*)/i        ? Thanks!